# Fundamental domain for nonmodular functions

Tags: group-theory, modular-forms, modular-function, modular-group

A fundamental domain for the modular group can be viewed a subset of the upper half plane $\mathbb H$ that contains exactly one point from every orbit of the $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ action on $\mathbb H$. This can be defined analogously for subgroups $G$ of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$. The notion carries over to modular forms and modular functions for $G$: If $G$ is a genus zero group the orbits of the images of $G$ under its Hauptmodul can be studied, and the two notions should agree.

For functions $f$ which are not modular under any subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ (such as the square root $\sqrt{E_4}$ of the Eisenstein series) such a region could be defined analogously: A minimal domain such that $f$ does not assume the same value for two distinct points inside that domain, but still assumes all possible values. Is such a concept studied in the literature? I would be very grateful for any hints. Thanks a lot!

Edit: Let us consider the example $f: \mathbb H \to \mathbb C$, $\tau\mapsto \frac{E_6(\tau)}{\sqrt{E_4(\tau)}^{3}}$ with $E_4$ and $E_6$ the Eisenstein series of weight $4$ and $6$. The function $f$ has an integer $q$-expansion $f(\tau)=1-864q+269568q^2+\mathcal O(q^3)$ with $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$, so it is holomorphic and invariant under $T:\tau\to \tau+1$. It has formally weight $0$. Under the $S$-transformation restricted to the imaginary axis $\tau=i \beta$, $\beta>0$, we have that $f(i/\beta)=-f(i \beta)$ since $E_6$ picks up a minus sign while there is none for $\sqrt{E_4}$ (this is unambiguous since $(i\beta)^4$ is real). So $f$ is anti-invariant under $S$, which does enlarge the $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ fundamental domain in such a way that a region around $0$ is also included in it. It seems to me that the associativity of the group action of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ on $\mathbb H$ does not carry over to such functions. It would be really interesting to understand this better!

Comment: In general, for a function $f : X \to Y$ you could define an eqivalence relation on $X$ by $x \sim_f x'$ iff $f(x) = f(x')$ and then look at the quotient $X / \sim_f$. You obtain a function $\tilde{f} : X / \sim_f \to Y$ in the obvious way (look up quotient space/topology if you want to give it a topology). But of course, this equivalence relation, and thus $X / \sim_f$ (and its topology) highly depend on $f$.

Comment: With $\sqrt{E_4}$ what do you mean, a function on which space, which analyticity and singularities

Comment: @PaulK Thanks for your insights. My comment was too long, so I edited the question. Please let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: why do you think that $f$ is not modular under any subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$ ?

Comment: also, is it the case that $E_4$'s zeroes all have even order ? how do you define its square root if they aren't ?

Comment: @mercio I don't have a proof. Such functions appear in physics and one can geometrically motivate why a possible fundamental region can not be the one of a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. The zeros of $E_4$ don't all have even order. By $\sqrt{}$ I mean the principal square root on $\mathbb C$. Is that an issue?

Comment: Yes, it is an issue. $f$ is clearly not holomorphic on $\mathbb H$. Depending on how you deal with the square root, either it's discontinuous (which is what you are going for with your principal square root) either it's meromorphic on some infinitely branched 2-cover of $\mathbb H$.

Comment: You should clarify what you meany by a "domain" and "function." From the context, you probably mean a holomorphic function from the upper half-plane to $CP^1$. Maybe you also assume invariance under some nontrivial discrete subgroup of $PSL(2,R)$. As for "domain," if you were a complex analyst, I'd say that you mean "open and connected subset." Since you appear to be an analytic number-theorist, I have no idea, you might mean "a set." Note that your definition of a fundamental domain is incorrect if "domain" is understood in "analyst's sense." The usual definition is more subtle.

Comment: @mercio Would it be possible to define $\sqrt{E_4}$ through its $q$-series?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks a lot for your comment. I was vague with my question on purpose since I don't understand what I'm going for precisely. As is customary in the theory of modular forms I aim for a fundamental domain as a semi-closure of a domain in the complex analysis sense (non-empty open connected). I am a physicist so please excuse my inaccuracy. I know how to construct fundamental domains for Fuchsian groups. So I am interested in such "domains" for meromorphic functions on $\mathbb H$ which are not necessarily modular.

Comment: I see, just to confirm: You do not assume any invariance (under some, possibly nonarithmetic lattice in $SL(2,R)$) properties from your functions, right? And when you say "meromorphic", do you allow essential singularities inside the upper half-plane?

Comment: the $q$-series doesn't converge on all of $\mathbb H$ but only on $\{ z \in \mathbb C \mid Im(z) > 1 \}$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am not familiar with nonarithmetic lattices in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$. Are fundamental domains for such groups defined? By meromorphic I would exclude essential singularities.

Comment: @mercio Ah this is interesting. How can I prove it?

Comment: @Rachmaninov: Yes, fundamental domains work for nonarithmetic lattices just as well. If your meromorphic function $f$ is automorphic with respect to a non-arithmetic lattices and has "good behavior" at the cusps, then one gets a reasonably nice fundamental domain for $f$. I am quite skeptical you can find a fundamental domain in general.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks a lot! Can you refer me to good literature on such nonarithmetic attices?

Comment: See for instance Beardon's book "The Geometry of Discrete Groups." Automorphic functions for non-arithmetic groups are discussed in "Discontinuous Groups and Automorphic Functions" by Joseph Lehner. It is a bit dated but will be easier for you to read.