# Square root of Eisenstein series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, modular-forms, modular-function, modular-group

I am interested in square roots of Eisenstein series, such as $\sqrt{E_4}$ (see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786652)). If we define the square root through its Taylor series,
$$\sqrt{E_4}(\tau)=1 + 120 q - 6120 q^2 + 737760 q^3+\mathcal O(q^4), \quad q=e^{2\pi i\tau}$$
is an integer $q$-series with integral coefficients. Using the root test or the quotient test I find that it converges for $|q|<0.004$ or $\text{Im}(\tau)>0.878$. Using the $S$-transformation
$$E_4(-1/\tau)=\tau^4E_4(\tau)$$
one could define $\sqrt{E_4}$ also near $\tau=0$ (or $q=1$). Can $\sqrt{E_4}$ in this way be turned into a holomorphic function on $\mathbb H$, using analytic continuation...? Is there a fundamental domain for $\sqrt{E_4}$ and would it just be given by two copies of a fundamental domain for $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zeros of the $E_4$ modular form occur at the points ${SL}_2(\Bbb Z)$-equivalent to
$\pm\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{-3}$. They are simple, so the largest half-plane
that $\sqrt{E_4}$ can be defined as a holomorphic function is $\{x+yi:y>\sqrt 3/2\}$.
This is equivalent to $|q|<\exp(-\sqrt3\pi)$. Does this agree with your numerics?

Comment: Hi again, and thanks for your answer. From the ratio or root test I do not get enough precision, however from the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ we have the constraint $|x|<1$. Since $E_4(\tau)=1+\mathcal O(q^1)$ this means that the boundary of convergence is $|E_4(\tau)|-1|=1$, such that it is enough to search for solutions to $E_4(\tau)=2$ on, say, the strip $-\frac1 2\leq\text{Re} \tau <\frac12$. This can be quite precisely solved as $\tau=0.8779966i$. This is strangely larger than the imaginary part of the zero of $E_4$, which is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sim 0.86602$. Do you have an idea why?